# Exams during MBBS

Tags: exams, international-students, medicine

What are the national and international competitive exams an Indian medical student can take during his/her undergraduate years (during MBBS)?

Specifically, I am looking for an international olympiad type competitive test on medical subjects (Anatomy, Physiology...) which I can apply from India.

Comment: Can you please say something about why you are asking this question and what you are really trying to accomplish?  Right now, this is a "make a big list" question, which is generally off-topic on this site.

Comment: I am looking for an international olympiad type competitive test on medical subjects (Anatomy, Physiology...) which I can apply from India.